# How to set a different position of a div if I insert a paragraph in my textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to set that if I press **enter** in my textarea between the words "Write Here" and "Guys", the two boxes with the words "Write" and "Here" should be displayed one next to the other orizontally, and the box with "Guys" should be under the "Write" one.

And if there are four words with the same example of before, the fourth box should be next to the "Guys" one.

In my code I wrote that all the boxes will display orizontally, if there is space to disply them, because I don't know how to put a box below the others if ther is an "enter space" in the textarea.

Whit the code is much easier to understand:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfamqvub/3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here
Guys</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button><br>
<div id='boxes'>
```

CSS:

```
#faketxt {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

.fakes{
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  display:inline-block;
}

#boxes{
  display : flex;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var wordLimit = 1;
  var words = primo.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
  if (words.length) {
    var count = 0;
    var div = createDiv();
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
      }
      if (div.innerHTML) {
        div.append(' ');
      }
      div.append(word);
    });
  }
});

function createDiv() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'fakes';
  document.getElementById('boxes').append(div);
  return div;
}
```

Comment: so what you want. as per your description all working good

Comment: split lines first, then split words on each line. Note that different browsers use different html to delimit lines though in conteneditable

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande I updated It.

Comment: @charlietfl Can you write what you mean as an answer?

Comment: @SamOnela Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var words = primo.innerText.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
```

replace below line

```
  if (div.innerHTML) {
    div.append(' ');
  }
```

with

```
  if (word == '') {
    div.className = '';
  }
```

Comment: @ Niccolò Guidi: text value previously(.innerHtml) was html now you will get only text value this is want you want right..?

Comment: could you be more specific about what you want and keep on adding some cases and changing values. what is the need for var wordLimit = 1

  if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
      }
remove above mentioned part  

words.forEach(function(word) {
    
    
        div = createDiv();
    
      if (word == '') {
    div.className = ' ';
      }
      div.append(word);
    });

Comment: I need that when I insert a text and I press enter in any place,  the function understands it and put the text after the "enter-space" in a div above the First div. It has to work everytime I press enter and also with different text. I think that it has to be set that if there is a "enter-space" the text after that has to be placed in a div under the First div of the line of div above, but I'm not sure.